# How can I discover what's making my android game freeze?

Tags: android

My android game freezes for several seconds (~10) sometimes...

I'm almost sure it's a "grow heap" problem, but I can't see any log or something like that anywhere (logcat, allocation tracker, etc)...

Is there any tool that can help me to see why it's freezing?

Comment: UI Usually freezes because of processing over UI thread. for games you would like to see SurfaceView class instead of subclassing View.
Take a survey of code as well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html, http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html, http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html Then you can check if you do any heavy operation in the UI thread.

Comment: All those tips and tools help me a lot, but I want something that show me exactly why my game is freezing at the moment it's freezing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can see you heap usage from tool called MAT, [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) is the
   Tuts , its plugin to eclipse , downlaod from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)..you can see
   statistic of heap plz refer tuts
2. It also shows which object is occupy more memory